# Python execution order in executable directory

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create an executable directory. It appears that the code in the **init**.py in one of my subpackages is executing before the **main**.py file in the root directory. Why is that?

Comment: Short answer: because _that's what `__init__` is for_. Python always loads the `__init__` module of a package before loading any modules that the package contains.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't describe any particular package structure in your question, all me to conjure up one for the sake of example. Let's say your package structure looks like the following:

```
package/
├── __init__.py
├── __main__.py
└── subpackage
    ├── __init__.py
    └── submodule.py
```

and that `package/__main__.py` contains

```
print("before import in", __name__)

import package.subpackage.submodule

print("after import in", __name__)
```

while the files `package/__init__.py`, `package/subpackage/__init__.py`, and `package/subpackage/submodule.py` all contain

```
print(__name__)
```

(Note that [`__name__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) is just a fancy global variable that holds the name of the current module).

If we try to run our package using the command

```
$ python3 -m package
```

we get the following output

```
package
before import in __main__
package.subpackage
package.subpackage.submodule
after import in __main__
```

This tells us that that package's top level `__init__` module was the first to be loaded by the interpreter, followed by `__main__`. In the process of running `__main__`, we encounter an `import` statement, which causes the interpreter to briefly halt execution to load the desired module. When loading a module, Python check whether each intermediate package has already been loaded. Any packages that haven't been loaded yet will be loaded first, so importing `package.subpackage.submodule` results in `package/subpackage/__init__.py` being run, followed by `package/subpackage/submodule.py`. Only once all this is completed does control return back to `__main__`.

In your package, the `__init__.py` of your subpackage is not executing *before* `__main__.py` per se. Rather, you main module is (presumably) importing a module from the subpackage, which results in the subpackage's `__init__` module being loaded, as demonstrated above.

Comment: More like this:
package/
├── __main__.py
└── subpackage
    ├── __init__.py
    └── submodule.py

Comment: So is there a way to have it execute a module in the main package before importing any of the subpackages? Or is that a "why on earth would you ever want to do that?" kind of thing?

Comment: @JoshSroka  If `__main__` imports anything, those modules will be run in their entirety at the time they are imported. If you need to perform some actions before other modules are loaded, you can always insert your code before the import statements in `__main__`. There may also be a more tidy approach possible, but we'd need to known a bit more about why you need certain modules to be run before others.